# MySql, Select, left join, group by, limit.. and where i've to place ORDER?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by

i've a very confusionary quesry string that at this moment appears like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS m.*,
(
  SELECT count(1) FROM votazioni_messaggi v
  WHERE v.idMeggaggio=m.ID
) AS Votato,

AVG(voto) AS votazioneMedia, 
n.nomeUtente,
FROM messages m 
LEFT JOIN votazioni_messaggi v ON v.idMessaggio = m.ID 
LEFT JOIN utenti n ON a.idUtente=n.ID
WHERE n.idUser='$idUser' AND m.Genre IN('animal', 'love') 
GROUP BY m.ID,  
LIMIT $partenza, 20
```

In other words, i've to select 20 messages at time that haves like genre "animals" and "love", for each of it retrieve info about user and calculate the vote average. Counting and grouping i can know if an user had already voted or not the message.

Now i've to set a last clause for ORDER messages BY insertion time (i've this data in messages.InsertionTime table).

The clause should be **ORDER BY messages.InsertionTime** but how i can know in what exact point i've to place it?

Comment: Before `LIMIT`, after `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Aldi: already tryied, but it give me Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Comment: You need to remove the comma after the `GROUP BY m.ID` and insert your `ORDER BY` there. I've fixed your code formatting; posting SQL surrounded by double-quotes breaks it. Please don't do so. :-) You can preview the code when posting it so you make sure the formatting is correct (immediately below the text area where you're typing/pasting your code).

Comment: Could you copy and paste full error message?

Comment: Aldi, the problem was the comma after the Group by, a very banal error :(

Comment: @AnnaLica Yup. Sorry I am careless, I didn't see the comma before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS m.*,
       (SELECT count(1) FROM votazioni_messaggi v
        WHERE v.idMeggaggio=m.ID
       ) AS Votato,
       AVG(voto) AS votazioneMedia, 
       n.nomeUtente,
FROM messages m 
LEFT JOIN votazioni_messaggi v ON v.idMessaggio = m.ID 
LEFT JOIN utenti n ON a.idUtente=n.ID
WHERE n.idUser='$idUser' AND m.Genre IN ('animal', 'love') 
GROUP BY m.ID
ORDER BY m.InsertionTime 
LIMIT $partenza, 20;
```

You had at least two problems.  One was a comma at the end of the `group by`.  The other was using the table name instead of the table alias.